# Problem with ROSARIA

Tags: ros-fuerte, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I have been had this problem for so long and I never could pass this step.
I install ros fuerte and install rosaria, just as is explained in the tutorial.
When I run the final command:
**rosrun ROSARIA RosAria**

I have:
**NonCritical Error: ARIA could not find where it is located.
[ INFO] [1358004426.341266265]: using port: [/dev/ttyUSB0]
ArLog::init:  File(aria.log)     Verbose     Logging Time    Not also printing
setup failed...**

Can someone help me? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52066/problem-with-rosaria/) by [alessandrayoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/3730/alessandrayoko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-01-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2013-03-26**:
Check the aria.log file for more log messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem and I solved it this way:

```
sudo chmod 775 /dev/ttyUSB0
sudo chown username:username /dev/ttyUSB0
```

---

Originally posted by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) with karma: 483 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JKS](https://answers.ros.org/users/357/jks/) on 2013-03-25**:
If this really boils down to permission issues with the serial port, the user connecting to the robot should be added to the dialout group: $ sudo usermod -a -G dialout username, after which you should logout and login again.